# Copy to clipboard is including parent of targeted element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, clipboard

**Edit - Additional info:**

**Simplified sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-leftpad-k6eek**

**Demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XHu1.jpg**

**Issue doesn't seem to be happening on firefox but is on chrome and other browsers**

---

I have a div that renders a template (simplified in above link) which is hooked up to a button that calls a function that copies to clipboard.

However when pasting what is copied to the clipboard, the contents is centered and upon further inspection the container div styles (`{ display: 'flex', margin: '0 auto', justifyContent: 'center' }`) are also included in what is selected.

How do I exclude the parent div from the copy, it should **only** be targeting the html code in the literal template (preferably just what I'm targeting by id - `#signature-preview-workspace`, therefore shouldn't be centered?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're already using NPM try the module named "Clipboard"

Comment: Are you using classes or functional components?

Comment: A class @MattOestreich

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in Firefox but when I paste, I get an empty line... How can I reproduce this?

Comment: [This is my reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jwz4fp) ... Is this how you are using it?

Comment: reproduction here: codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-leftpad-k6eek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, I completely misunderstood what you were looking for.. I thought you wanted *all* styles removed..

It seems the fix for this is simply just wrapping the "template" you want to copy in a `div` without any styles applied to it..

Here is a [demo using Gmail](https://i.imgur.com/9AhIiBZ) in Chrome..

```js
const { useRef, useCallback } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  const copyTextToClipboard = el => {
    let range = document.createRange(0);
    range.selectNode(el);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  };

  const handleCopyClick = useCallback(() => {
    copyTextToClipboard(
      ref.current.querySelector("#signature-preview-workspace")
    );
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{ display: "flex", margin: "0 auto", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                <table id="signature-preview-workspace" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="color: red;">Contents here...</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </body>
            </html>
          `
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => handleCopyClick()}>Copy</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Woo! Wonder why that is, anyways that's done the job. Thanks so much @MattOestreich for your patience, legend.

Comment: Happy to help - thanks for putting up with all of my questions and imgur links lol.. Glad we were able to get this resolved!! Cheers  EDIT: to elaborate, I think this happens because you are setting the inner HTML of the `div` that has styles applied, therefore the contents of that `div` inherit those styles?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ref` instead of a direct document search.

```js
const copyTextToClipboard = el => {
  const range = document.createRange(0);
  range.selectNode(el);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  document.execCommand("copy");
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
};

const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const handleCopyClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    copyTextToClipboard(
      ref.current.querySelector("#signature-preview-workspace")
    );
  }, [ref]);

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{ display: "flex", margin: "0 auto", justifyContent: "center" }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
                <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                <table id="signature-preview-workspace" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Contents here...</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </body>
            </html>
          `
        }}
      />

      <div>
        <button onClick={handleCopyClick}>Copy text above</button>
      </div>

      <textarea placeholder="Paste copied..." />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

You have another problem. You're using `p` as a child of `tr` which is incorrect and leads to the empty text copied. Change `p` to `td`.

Comment: Solid answer. Just for my own sanity - are you using `useCallback` to prevent that method from being recreated on each re-render?

Comment: A cleaner approach so thank you but unfortunately a div with the styles is still wrapping the template when I paste into a text area `<div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display, Montserrat, sans-serif; font-size: medium; display: flex; margin: 0px auto; justify-content: center;"></div>`

Comment: @Apswak what browser do you use?

Comment: @teimurjan Brave/Chrome, I have recreated it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-leftpad-k6eek if you click on copy and paste it into a text field (could even be gmail's email compose textinput) you'll see it's centered and upon inspection it's got the styles of the div that is rendering the template

Comment: In that simplified example you'll see it seems to copy the button too?

Comment: @Apswak when I try in your CodeSandbox, it is the same result as my StackBlitz example (in the 'main' comments).. Nothing gets copied, except for whitespace. Even in Chrome.... is this happening to you in Chrome or just Brave? If Chrome, which version?

Comment: @teimurjan - sorry for going off on a tangent... how do you know when to use `useCallback` and when not to? Why is it a bad idea to use it on every method?

Comment: @MattOestreich please try again now, for some reason wasn't the latest version

Comment: @MattOestreich Yes but not on chrome

Comment: @Apswak - [works just fine on Chrome for me... what version of Chrome are you using?](https://i.imgur.com/C8FlEf6.mp4)

Comment: @MattOestreich please see example here https://imgur.com/a/SDWTQno using gmail compose

Comment: I suppose we need to take a step back then... perhaps the logic here is flawed.. I assume the data you want to copy is from the table? Or is it a certain row in the table? How does that data get populated? Can you elaborate a little more on the background here? @Apswak

Comment: @Apswak if you change to plain text mode it works fine.. https://i.imgur.com/95hfxfj.mp4

Comment: @MattOestreich plain text mode isn't an option as it doesn't maintain styles (loses red)

Comment: I'm basically building a template builder that must be copy-able via a button so you can paste it and maintain styles, WITHOUT those parent styles that is causing centering

Comment: @Apswak sorry about that.. just added a new answer that solves this. Apologies for my confusion!